# How to disable curly braces evaluation in URL passed to HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets, curly-braces

I have a URL shortner that should sendRedirect(URL) to URLs specified by users. 
Sometimes URL contain curly braces like this: `http://example.com?someparam={something}`.

Instead of sending response 302 to client browser, my Spring MVC app at Tomcat server gives error 404 with no text.

Apparently it's some sort of URL variable evaluation taking place, can I disable it? I could not find docs regarding this feature.

Comment: I am not sure if it works because I haven't tried but I think you can encode your url

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera Encode to what? only `{}` should be encoded, not full URL. I want to avoid custom code hassle if it's a matter of config.

Comment: You should encode Url String after your domain name using URL encoder.

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera 1. it's not config solution which I ask for. 2. Such encoding will break some other params. In the end I will have to write some good unit tested code to escape {} and I don't want to, as it's probably a config flag somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I think the OP was looking for a way to prevent Spring from doing variable replacement in redirect URL

I faced the exact same issue and the fix was using RedirectView
and in RedirectView you can set setExpandUriTemplateVariables(false)

that made it redirect to the url given exactly without Spring trying to replace anything in it

here is how the code looks like

```
        RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView(redirectUrl);
        redirect.setExpandUriTemplateVariables(false);
        return new ModelAndView(redirect);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Google search URL `http://google.com/{something}`. It should have been `https://www.google.ca/search?q=http{302}`

Emphasis is on **search?q**. After domain name you have specify your service name and then query string if you want to pass some inputs.

When you do `http://google.com/{something}` then you really do not have any resource or service as `{something}` so 404 is the expected output.

HTTP 302 is for redirection, I am not sure why you were expecting redirection.

URL encoding will also not help because issue is related to resource/service, if it is not present then you will get 404. URL encoding is not meant to solve problem related to 404.

Comment: It's not about google. My app gives error 404 instead of 302 redirect to google, bacause of braces presence.

Comment: Can you put more explanation on what is being passed in client side, what your server is doing .. You have to understand 404 means server do have that resource, whether your server or your redirection to Google, if resource is present and then 404 will not happen and then 302 will happen .. You cannot expect to get 302 if resource itself is not present in first place .. Please put more information in your question, starting from client till your redirection ..

Comment: I use response.sendRedirect(URL) and expect that server responds 302 redirect to client. If URL is `http://example.com/param=whatever` all good, I get 302. If URL is `http://example.com/param={whatever}` - I get 404 in response to client. My server definitely should not care whether resource at that the end exists or not exists. It's a matter of response from example.com where client browser will send next reques.

Comment: You better give exact URL, because `http://example.com/param=whatever` is not a valid URL ..

Comment: It does not matter whether it's valid or not, really. Whatever it is, a browser should be sent redirect to it so it will figure out further....

Comment: You are not getting the point, you cannot get redirection until you resolve 404 .. If the resource itself is not there then where redirection will happen ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103927/discussion-between-snowindy-and-hagrawal).